# UNIX find word after certain number of occurences of '-'

Tags: unix, numbers

Suppose I have a file in the form of

```
word word word - word - word word - ...
```

In other words, some words interspersed by some dashes (-). How can I find (in UNIX) the word that occurs after, say, the 849th dash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this perl one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'print "$2\n" if m{^([^-]+\-){849}\s*(\w+)}' infile;
```

If you are looking for the word before the 849th dash do:

```
perl -ne 'print "$2\n" if m{^([^-]+\-){848}.+?\s*(\w+)\s*\-}' infile;
```

Comment: Thanks! What about the word _before_ the 849th dash? (Sorry I don't know Perl.)

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming the data is all on one line)

Cut in this case will be you friend

```
echo "Hello-World-I-Love-You" | cut -d- -f2
> World
```

The `-d-` says which character(s) delineated the fields and `-f2` is the field number.  `man cut` will tell you more.

```
cut -d- -f849 < infile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"-" '{split($850,a," ");print a[1];}' file
```